# Changing default ID field for Neo4j with Spring Data

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

When using [Spring-Data-Neo4j-4](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/), it seems that everything returned for the default REST API's CRUD operations is tied to the internal ID that Neo4j assigns to the various Node and Relationship types.

The problem is, those IDs have no real value to clients using our service that we are building on top of Spring Data.  If I want to delete a Person node, for example, I'd have to first do a query to retrieve the internal Neo4j ID (perhaps it's 1234), then I would be able to issue the DEL call against the CRUD API.

```
DEL http://myserver/person/1234
```

But in my world, we recognize a Person in our systems based upon a user ID or a GUID code.  What can be done to have Spring Data use our own unique identifiers so that I could make the above delete call by using by username, `moryl`, as the ID instead?  That would let me do CRUD on users with IDs known to other systems in our network, and without having to make an additional call to translate our chosen ID field to the Neo4j ID by doing a MATCH/RETURN query.

Is there any simple way to do it, or will I have to basically rewrite a lot of the CRUD functionality methods that Spring Data is user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `Delete` capability of the OGM session, there is also no possibility to delete a node without loading it before hand :

```
interface Delete {
        <T> void delete(T object);
        <T> void deleteAll(Class<T> type);
        void purgeDatabase();
        void clear();
    }
```

You can however use a `@Query` in your repository for deleting nodes based on an given argument to your rest api, for example :

```
//src/main/java/school/repository/StudentRepository
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends GraphRepository<Student> {

    @Query("MATCH (s:Student) WHERE s.name = {0} DELETE s")
    void deleteStudentByName(String name);

}
```

--

```
//src/main/java/school/controller/StudentController
@RequestMapping("/api/student/delete/{name}")
    public void deleteStudent(String name) {
        studentRepository.deleteStudentByName(name);
    }
```

This would avoid to load the Student entity at all.

That said, using custom id strategies is being thought, this is not trivial though.